# JSF or JSF with SpringMVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsf, jakarta-ee

I am having a Project with J2EE that's not very big , i began using JSF and i found it very nice and easy , but by the time i was searching on the internet i found a integration called JSF and SpringMVC , so i am wondering is that a better way to develop application and is it recomanded for me to use it or i'll be doing fine with jsf all alone.

i saw this link

http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-integration-example/

Comment: That tutorial is Spring + JSF, not Spring MVC + JSF.

Comment: JSF2 is a good modern web development framework. If you would like to learn how to use it, I can't recommend BalusC's curated list of [JSF resources](https://jsf.zeef.com/bauke.scholtz) highly enough.

Answer (score 0):

Both JSF and SpringMVC are implementations of the MVC pattern, so using both framework together is not the best design approach. JSF is a component based framework but SpringMVC is a request based. However you can use both together to get benefit of the SpringSecuirty framework if you need security features in your applications. Another advantage from my point of view is you can use Spring IoC features without the need to use EJB and run your application in a normal web container like tomcat.

Finally, it's your decision based on your requirements.

Answer (score -1):

That tutorial is talking about spring+JSF and not springMVC+JSF.
If you don't know anything about spring you should be doing fine JSF all alone.
There is no a better way nor a worse, they are just showing how you can integrate spring with jsf.